# Error in installing Flask_mysqldb in PyCharm

Tags: flask, pycharm, flask-mysql

Hi everyone I am installing Flask_mysqldb in Pycharm and I am experiencing problem.
Is seems to be the only library that I am not able to install.[image]

Answer (score 1):

can you please check the details on the installation panel down there.

Another way to install package is to open terminal tap down on left of package tap and run this command

```
pip install flask-mysqldb
```